# Load image NOT from .xcassets folder?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, storyboard, xcasset

I have a localized app for iOS. I localized my images and set them to views from code. I removed localized images from .xcassets and now that images are in some folder 'localized_images'. But now some views in storyboard were left empty. How can I set an image for imageview in storyboard not from .xcasset folder but from my folder 'localized_images'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type the name of the image with its extension(exampleImage.png) in the attribute inspector

Also if you want 1x 2x 3x images you have to create Asset catalog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do same way as you set when it is in `.xcassets` ! In storyboard select your `imageview` and from `attribute inspector` select image. If you can not found image then type its name and hit enter! that's it!